# Alternating between two images on a background thread

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

I'm relatively new to C# so still learning a lot as I go.

On a Form I'm trying to change an image of an LED from one colour to another sleep for a second then change back

I want the process to run asynchronously so it doesn't block the main thread that it's called from.
So far no changes are happening and I'm not sure why it's not working.

I've created a task like this

```
    public async Task ChangeCallLed()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                Globals.mForm.sndPageCall_lbl.Image = Resources.led_green_black;
                Globals.mForm.sndPageCall_lbl.Update();
            });
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                Globals.mForm.sndPageCall_lbl.Image = Resources.led_blue_black;
                Globals.mForm.sndPageCall_lbl.Update();
            });
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                Globals.mForm.sndPageCall_lbl.Image = Resources.led_amber_black;
                Globals.mForm.sndPageCall_lbl.Update();
            });
        });
    }
```

And I'm calling the task in the main thread a few times like this
`Task.Run(ChangeCallLed);`

Edit: global variables:

```
static class Globals { 
    public static MainForm mForm; 
    public static PagerCall pCall; 
}
```

Edit: main method call:

```
static void Main() { 
    ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize(); 
    Globals.mForm = new MainForm(); 
    Globals.pCall = new PagerCall(); 
    //Globals.beepDetected = new BeepDetected(); 
    Application.Run(Globals.mForm); 
}
```

When the main thread has finished it flashes (as the code above means it too) I just don't get what I'm doing wrong.

I have tried many ways, like making the main thread the call is on as Async but no change. I just want to make the led appear to flash without blocking the main thread.

Comment: It is unclear why exactly this isn't working. You need to provide more details, e.g. what exactly `Globals.mForm.sndPageCall_lbl` is. Please also clarify if the is really about WPF and not WinForms. It looks like the latter.

Comment: Does the image change but the code blocks the main thread? Or does the image not change? If it is just blocking the thread then try to use `Task.Delay(1000)` instead of `Thread.Sleep(1000)`. The latter blocks the thread while Task.Delay doest not, if i recall correctly.

Comment: Sorry it is the WinForms, and in program.cs I have     static class Globals
    {
        public static MainForm mForm;
        public static PagerCall pCall;
    }
    
        static void Main()
        {
            ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();

            Globals.mForm = new MainForm();
            Globals.pCall = new PagerCall();
            //Globals.beepDetected = new BeepDetected();
            Application.Run(Globals.mForm);
            
        }
    }
}

Comment: It doesn't change until the main thread has finished

Comment: "until the main thread has finished" That would mean the process ends. If you meant the main thread is doing something else then that is a problem. Only the main thread can change the UI. So if the main thread does something currently that needs to be put somewhere else as Task or Thread so the Main Thread is free and ready to do UI updates.

Comment: I see that you've added some clarifying code in a previous comment. Could you please hit the [**Edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75695302/edit) link and add that to the question itself? Also when you say **I'm calling the task in the main thread a few times like this: `Task.Run(ChangeCallLed)`** one could take that to mean you're calling a Task that runs a Task. Let's see code also for exactly what these calls look like and an example of what causes it (e.g. is it a button click or some other event?) Basically, we're looking for just enough code to be able to reproduce your issue. Thx!

Comment: Seems you're doing this to indicate that the UI is still active, but waiting for some kind of expensive operation to complete.  Problem is: it isn't active.  The Invoke() call will just stall until it gets active again.  If that is accurate then keep in mind that you're doing this the wrong way around.  Always keep the main thread responsive, do whatever takes time on a worker thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post states that you're

> trying to change an image of an LED from one colour to another sleep for a second then change back.

Here, in general form, is one way to go about updating a UI element (e.g. to change color or image) at a specific time interval without blocking the UI thread.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        buttonFlash.Click += onClickFlash;
    }

    private void onClickFlash(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _ = ChangeCalled();
    }        

    private async Task ChangeCalled()
    {
        foreach (var color in new Color[] 
        {
            Color.LightGreen,
            Color.CornflowerBlue,
            Color.Goldenrod,
        })
        {
            led1.BackColor= color;
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }
        led1.BackColor = Color.DimGray;
    }
}
```

[image: cycle led]

Where:

```
class LED : Label
{
    protected override void OnCreateControl()
    {
        base.OnCreateControl();
        var region = new Region(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, ClientSize));
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        graphics.FillEllipse(
            Brushes.LimeGreen,
            new RectangleF(
                new PointF(4, 4),
                new SizeF(bitmap.Width - 8, bitmap.Height - 8)));
        for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x++) for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++)
            {
                Color pixel = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
                if (pixel.ToArgb() != Color.LimeGreen.ToArgb())
                {
                    region.Exclude(new Rectangle(x, y, 1, 1));
                }
            }
        Region = region;
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        using (var pen = new Pen(Color.White, 2)) 
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(
                pen,
                new RectangleF(
                    new PointF(6, 6),
                    new SizeF(Width - 12, Height - 12)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you I've tried creating a new form with the above code but don't know what led1.BackColor is, is it a label that I need to add to the form ? Sorry if this obvious to most just unclear as to how to make this work in a test form

Comment: No problem, thx for letting me know! Perhaps it would be more clear if you [clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/flash-led.git) the demo code that I used to test this answer. Let me know if you have any trouble doing this. To answer your question, though, the "LED" on this form is a class that inherits `Label` and so `BackColor` is a property of `Label`.

Comment: To answer your other question, I've found that often the easiest way to put a custom version of a control on the Form is to place a normal `Label` using the designer and then swap it out by editing the Designer.cs code by hand. I hope I didn't make too much of a distraction with the `LED:Label` class when I was really trying to answer the threading question!

Comment: Cool thanks just having a look at what you've done :)

Comment: So I've added that class and function to the code but when I call it, it changes to the first colour then literally waits until the routine it was called from has finished then changes through the colours. I've uploaded the whole project **[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N7Hu7n3V9uuTco-dmLrxQm0pa5dK3_sO/view?usp=share_link)**

Comment: You're talking about PagerCall_Led()? This is a little tough because, while your project builds, there's no database server of course so I can't really reproduce what you're seeing. But try a redraw here, see if it helps `PCallLED.BackColor = color; PCallLED.Refresh();`

Answer (score 0):

For windows form. I would recommend you to try [BackgroundWorker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=net-7.0). It 's provided 'ReportProgress' event change/update control in UI thread without additional code.

If you want to create Thread/Task manually. You must do 'Invoke' to UI Thread for access his resource. This required additional code you must to implement and understand. Example. [Thread-Safe Control](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/asynchronous-calls-and-threadsafe-control-usage-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer) instead of threading. This way you won't have to worry about thread safety and coordination. Set the [`Interval`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer.interval?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) of your timer to `1000`, and put this code in the `Tick` event handler:

```
private int _sndPageCall_Index = 0;

private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (_sndPageCall_Index++ % 3)
    {
        case 0: Globals.mForm.sndPageCall_lbl.Image = Resources.led_green_black; break;
        case 1: Globals.mForm.sndPageCall_lbl.Image = Resources.led_blue_black; break;
        case 2: Globals.mForm.sndPageCall_lbl.Image = Resources.led_amber_black; break;
    }
}
```

You can start and stop the timer with the `Enabled` property, or the `Start`/`Stop` methods.